# property substitution as com.google.guava 19

Tags: java, guava, maven-profiles

I've been using com.google.guava 19 for a while now for property substitution.

I have maven pom profiles

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <environment>dev</environment>
      ...
```

with below pom details

```
<!-- Add configuration for property substitution -->
<build>
    <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/resources/config.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

That replaces environment=${environment} in the config file with the profile property.

How can I do this in the later versions or is there a lighter way of doing this without using spring?

Comment: How is Guava related to property substitution? Aren't you just using the Maven resources plugin there?

Comment: I'm not sure but it doesn't work without guava.

Comment: I bet it doesn't work without a lot of other things too.

Comment: I've been using this: https://prismoskills.appspot.com/lessons/Maven/Chapter_07_-_Maven_profiles_and_property_substitution.jsp

Comment: It seems to be using Guava...for the test case. I don't see it actually *requiring* Guava. It's the maven plugin that does the work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that guava 30.0-jre reintroduces these capabilities and no other changes are required.